# Vue JS rendering HTML elements

Tags: html, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

```
<input type="file" name="" value="">
  <button type="button" name="button">Add More Pictures</button>
```

I created a file uploader and a button next to it.
What I want is, If I hit the "**Add More Pictures**" button another file uploader with another Add More Pictures button should be load below the button.

How can I do this using VueJS?

Comment: Let me know how it goes for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a **range-based loop** that creates fields as a numeric vm property increases.

```
<div v-for="n in uploadFieldCount" :key="n">
  <input type="file" name="" value="">
  <button type="button" name="button" @click="uploadFieldCount++">Add More Pictures</button>
</div>
```

and add that property in the data section of your vm:

```
data() {
  return {
    uploadFieldCount: 1 // initialize with the number of initial file uploads you need
  }
}
```

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot. =) and Is there a way to remove elements from the that rendered elements. (Using a "Remove this file upload" button)

Comment: You an always remove the last one using `uploadFieldCount--`.

Comment: It seems to me that `v-for` should be used with `key` property. To ensure that the input values are not lost after adding another.

Comment: @Ruslan Though this is only a requirement if using `v-for` on components, it does not hurt adding it. Done.